# Sharepoint - Custom error messages

Tags: sharepoint, message

I'm a beginner sharepoint developer for a work project.
Specifications ask for custom error message.
When I create a list with a number field the error message is "Only numbers can go here".

```
<Field Name="Libelle" ID="{487dfca6-af3c-4939-94b1-2e5ae5aefb44}" DisplayName="Libelle" Type="Number" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" Required="TRUE" />
```

Can I change this?

Comment: Relevant code could be so helpful

Comment: <Field Name="Libelle" ID="{487dfca6-af3c-4939-94b1-2e5ae5aefb44}" DisplayName="Libelle" Type="Number" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" Required="TRUE" />

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to make a code display on stackoverflow...

Comment: @JonhBn write a javascript for that and Add your javascript using content Editor webpart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation message for the `SPField` is a property on the field called `ValidationMessage` in the `Microsoft.SharePoint` namespace, or `validationMessage` in the `SP` namespace if you are working with the `SP.js` framework.

The validation message is controlled from a property that differs depending on what model you are using when developing towards SharePoint.

- `Field.ValidationMessage` in the  `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace
- `SP.Field.validationMessage` in the `SP.js` namespace
- `SPField.ValidationMessage` in the `Microsoft.SharePoint` namespace

---

**Using C# to set the validation message on `SPField`**

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    //Get the list with your field
    SPList list = web.Lists["Your list name here"];

    //Get the field
    SPField field = list["FieldName"];
    field.ValidationMessage = "Your custom validation message.";
}
```

---

**Using JSOM to set the validation message on `SP.Field`**

```
function setValidationMessage() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Your list title");
    var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Your field title or internal name");

    field.set_validationMessage("Your new validation message");
    field.update();

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    console.log("Validation message successfully updated!");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log("Failed to update validation message!");
}
```

---

**Using the Sharepoint REST api to set the validation message on `SP.Field`**

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(listid)/fields(fieldid)/validationMessage",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.Field'
        },
        'validationMessage': 'Your custom validation message!'
    }),
    headers: {
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method":"PATCH",
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
});
```

Additional info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245632.aspx).

---

You can also set the validation message from the settings in the SharePoint site by going to the column in site settings, select "Validation" and the "Validation message".

Answer (score -1):

Open your list like this:-

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/Lists/List Title/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=
```

**Note:- Replace 'List Title' with your List Title**

Edit this page and add 'Content Editor WebPart'(under 'Media and Content')
In content Editor Webpart Paste this script:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[title='Libelle']").blur(function(){
  var txt = $("input[title='Libelle']").val();
  if(!isNumber(txt)){
   $("input[title='Libelle']").val("");
   alert('Only numbers can go here');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```